# I can't connect with Xcode Swift app to Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I followed all kinds of tutorials and tried different things, but no help. I'm sure I did everything correctly. But when I'm trying to sign in with email, nothing is happing in Firebase(any new user or data). Also, I didn't receive any error message.

I think I couldn't connect ti firebase properly. There might be version mismatch on Cocoapods or Xcode or Firebase but I couldn't figure out.

- cocoapods-1.2.1
- Xcode 8.3.3
- Swift 3

---

AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
}
```

---

ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var passTextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func signUp(_ sender: Any) {

        let email = emailTextField.text!
        let password = passTextField.text!

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))
            }else{
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome", sender: self)
            }

        }
    }
```

---

Console output:

```
2017-06-12 05:17:22.628 emailAuth[11936] <Warning> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS005000] The AdSupport Framework is not currently linked. Some features will not function properly. Learn more at url.com
2017-06-12 05:17:22.636 emailAuth[11936] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.4001000 started
2017-06-12 05:17:22.636 emailAuth[11936] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see url.com)
2017-06-12 05:17:22.637 emailAuth[11936] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS003007] Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2017-06-12 05:17:22.678 emailAuth[11936] <Warning> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS032003] iAd framework is not linked. Search Ad Attribution Reporter is disabled.
2017-06-12 05:17:22.695 emailAuth[11936] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase Analytics enabled
2017-06-12 05:17:23.992594+0300 emailAuth[11936:2101062] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/mmuazekici/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4F8B6824-4D8D-4FB4-9E06-BFB49F220240/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-06-12 05:17:23.992826+0300 emailAuth[11936:2101062] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
```

Comment: You need to add code, so we know what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

Podfile :-

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
```

Drag and drop Google-plist in project

```
GoogleService-Info.plist
```

Add following code in AppDelegate

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FIRApp.configure()
}
```

Step-1

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
```

Step -2
Login action

```
 guard let email = txtFldUserID.text?.lowercased(), let password = txtFldPassword.text else { return }
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user: FIRUser?, error) in

            if let error = error as NSError?{

                let errorName = (error.userInfo as NSDictionary).value(forKey: "error_name") as! String
                proxy.shared.displayFirbaseError(errName: errorName)
                return
            }else{
                 proxy.shared.displayStatusCodeAlert("You are login successfully")
  }
```

Comment: I think I'm using new version of Firebase, because when I try "FIRApp.configure()", Xcode is saying "FIRApp has been renamed to FirebaseApp". There some little differences but I'm following the documentation and mine should be correct.